# Summoned too much items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was building a One Command Block Creation (Uranium mod), then i decided to test my Anti-radiation helmet crafting. It started summoning helmets as it should (repeating commandblock) but than it lagged my world forever - items were still summoning...
The problem is - i can't access this world, because it just lags MC.
There are many commandblock and stuff i really need, but is there any way i can save it or i've just lost hours of work?
Tried using MCEdit but it crashed all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [MCEdit-Unified](https://khroki.github.io/MCEdit-Unified/) or the old version of MCEdit, if you still use the old version then I recommend trying Unified.

If that didn't work then try to open the region file that holds the entities (probably be the largest one in data size) with [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac). Find the chunk that contains the entities, open it and delete the 'Entities' tag.
Save and close, now the items should be gone.

Comment: I used "old version". Didnt know about Unified - it worked fine.